# Setup and workflow when developing using a GitHub repo as initial codebase

Tags: git, github

I am new to git. So please treat me like a newbie.

I have a situation where my team has to do development taking a GitHub repo as the initial codebase. We are not contributing to this original repo but want to keep getting any updates that are available on the original GitHub repo from time to time into our repo. So effectively, I need a repo on GitHub which:

1. is initially cloned or forked from a GitHub repo
2. is used by my team for pushing their changes (regular dev activity - DVCS)
3. gets updates from the original GitHub repo from time to time.

Please guide on the initial setup and the daily commands/workflow.

So far I have tried the following:

**Initial Workflow:**

1. Created a fork of the original GitHub repo.
2. Cloned the fork onto a local machine (local-repo)

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/fork/devfiles.git project
   ```
3. Added the original GitHub repo as a remote

   ```
   cd project
   git remote add upstream https://github.com/original/devfiles.git
   ```
4. Created an empty repo on bitbucket to be used as a DVCS for my dev team, and added that as a second remote.

   ```
   git remote add devrepo git@bitbucket.org:mycomp/devfiles.git
   ```
5. From my local machine, push the forked repo onto bitbucket

   ```
   git push devrepo master
   ```
6. My dev team clones the bitbucket repo on their local machines

   ```
   git clone git@bitbucket.org:mycomp/devfiles.git
   ```

**Daily Workflow**

1. The dev team works with the bitbucket repo, pushing their changes to it.
2. To get updates from devrepo into local-repo, I run:

   ```
   git fetch devrepo (did not do what I wanted)
   git pull devrepo master (this works)
   ```
3. To get updates from the original GitHub repo into the local repo. I do the following:

   ```
   git fetch upstream
   git rebase upstream/master
   ```

This gets the latest commits of the original GitHub repo and plays my teams commits onto them.

Everything seems to be working fine until this point.

4. Now finally I need to push these updated files to devrepo

   ```
   git push devrepo master

   To git@bitbucket.org:mycomp/devfiles.git
    ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
   error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:mycomp/devfiles.git'
   hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
   hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
   hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
   hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a self-described git newbie, I feel I must educate you on a couple points.

> `git fetch devrepo (this does not work)`

I am going to go on an assumption here that you expect the above command to change the files in your working folder to something that represents the current state of `devrepo` merged in with whatever state your working folder is currently in, because in the next statement you say:

> `git pull devrepo master (this works)`

It is important to understand the distinction between [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch), [`git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) and [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull). `git pull` is a convenient way to do the extremely common `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`. Saying that `git fetch` doesn't work is (to put it bluntly) simply wrong, it would be more accurate to say:

> `git fetch` (did not do what I wanted)

---

With that out of the way, we can try to address your problem.

A couple points stand out to me based on your command history:

- You run `git pull` to **merge** commits from `devrepo/master` to your local branch. This updates your master branch pointer, and if you have made *any* commits to your local `master` branch that do not exist on `devrepo`, there will be merge commits created for you. Your local `master` branch has `devrepo/master` as a parent though, so this would not cause your `push` to fail.
- Following a merge you run a `rebase`. I personally have never tried to rebase a merge commit onto another branch, but I would guess that the problem lies here. My guess, (based on how I have seen git treat merge commits with other, unrelated commands) is that the rebase skips over the commit created when you ran `git pull` above. This would certainly put your `master` branch into the non-fast-forward state that `git pull` is telling you about.

To fix your workflow, you could do the following. (NOTE: this is not the only viable solution, just the one I think is most straight forward)

1. Fetch all the new commits from both repos:
   `git fetch devrepo`
   `git fetch upstream`
2. Checkout a temporary branch at devrepo/master:
   `git checkout -b tmp_master devrepo/master`
3. Pull in the upstream changes (this probably creates a merge commit):
   `git pull upstream master`
4. Switch back to your `master` branch
   `git checkout master`
5. Rebase onto tmp_master
   `git rebase tmp_master`
6. Delete temporary branch
   `git branch -D tmp_master`

You should now be able to `git push devrepo` without receiving that error message.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I now understand why git fetch did not work and have edited my question based on your feedback.

Comment: Do you have a typo at step 2. `git checkout` instead of `git clone` worked for me.

Comment: The workflow you have given works beautifully for me. But I am unable to understand step 5. `git rebase tmp_master` will take tmp_master as the base and play all the extra commits of master onto it. But it is `tmp_master` that has the extra commits, not `master`.

Comment: `git rebase` does not move tmp_master. The command `git rebase tmp_master` is run when you are on the `master` branch, so the command will replay the uncommon commits of the `master` branch on top of the `tmp_master` ***and*** `master` will be updated as a result.

Comment: In other words, if the commit history of `tmp_master` looks like A->B->C and the commit history of `master` looks like A->D->E then after `git rebase tmp_master` is run on the `master` branch, you will get a `master` that looks like A->B->C->D'->E' where D' and E' are new commit-id's. `tmp_master` still points to C